# Exe not working properly outside of visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022

My program runs fine in the IDE (Visual Studio 2022), in debug and release modes.

When I make a build and want to start the `.exe` from Explorer, it starts and runs, but... well, have a look:

This is how it should be:

[image: IDE output]

This is what it looks like outside of VS:

[image: EXE output]

So far, I have tried to set the Runtime Library to Multi-threaded (/MT), but that didn't work.

Otherwise, I really don't seem to find much. It seems the standalone `.exe` is missing some dependencies, but I can't figure out what I need to do. From my understanding, everything I have included in the header should get compiled "into" the `.exe` as well.

The `int128_t` doesn't seem to work. Neither do the ANSI color codes.
The timer is working, though.

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;

bool isPrime(mp::int128_t n);
mp::int128_t n{ 0 }, y{ 0 };

int main()
{
    std::cin >> y;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << "\n";
    
    for (y; y <= n; y++)
    {
        int lengthy = to_string(y).length();

        const auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

        if (isPrime(y) == true)
            std::cout << "\033[1;7;32m" << std::setw(lengthy) << std::left << y << "\033[0m ";
        else
        {
            std::cout << std::setw(lengthy) << std::left << y << " ";
        }

        const auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = end - start;

        if (elapsed.count() >= 0.1)
            std::cout << "\033[1;7;36m" << std::setw(10) << std::left << elapsed.count() << "\033[0m ";
        else
        {
            std::cout << "\033[1;36m" << std::setw(10) << std::left << elapsed.count() << "\033[0m ";
        }
    } 

    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cin >> y;
}

bool isPrime(mp::int128_t n)
{
    if (n == 2 || n == 3)
        return true;
    
    if (n <= 1 or n % 2 == 0 or n % 3 == 0)
        return false;
    
    for (uint64_t i = 5; i * i <= n; i += 6)
    {
        if (n % i == 0 or n % (i + 2) == 0)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: "Have a look". What do I see, and what is expected to be seen?

Comment: _"The int128_t doesnt seem to work."_ How have you determined this?

Comment: The cmd prompt doesn't accept your control characters for color

Comment: Since it is a `cout` formatting issue, could you please eliminate unneeded dependencies from your code?

Comment: Picture 2 should look like picture 1.
int128_t is determined in the boost library.
Thats sad. Why are the consoles different? 
As far as i am aware it is not a cout formatting issue. How and why would it be? And what unneeded dependencies you mean?

Comment: @386 I meant `boost` and `isPrime` and everything else. One-liner with your `std::cout` has the same issue. As pointed out above - 'console' problem

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701?activetab=pivot:overviewtab

Comment: This is not a solution. The program should run on any pc. 
I am aware that there are possibly solutions to this. You seem to be able to make the windows console recognize ansi color codes. It uses windows.h though.

Comment: @VladFeinstein It is not unneeded code. My integers are not working as well.

Comment: @386 console output is platform-specific. In this case, the Windows console simply doesn't support what you are trying to do.  You could try using a cross-platform wrapper like ncurses, otherwise there are Win32 API functions you can use rather than `cout` to output colored text to a console, namely `SetConsoleTextAttribute()` w/ `WriteConsole()`, or `WriteConsoleOutput()`

Comment: @DrewDormann I think i misunderstood what you meant. You meant how did i determine that the int128_t was not working i guess. In the first picture, do you see the numbers 1..100 counting up? They are not there in the second picture.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It seems it does. It´s just off as standard. I didnt try it yet, but it should work.  See other comments.

Comment: @386 Re: `do you see the numbers 1..100 counting up? They are not there in the second picture` - but they are! I can see `1`<garbage>`duration`<garbage>`2` etc.

Comment: Well.. this is awkward. I´ll mark your comment down low as answered. Sorry all and thanks for help. Ill get some sleep i guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code, specifically:

> In 2016, Microsoft released the Windows 10 version 1511 update which unexpectedly implemented support for ANSI escape sequences, over two decades after the debut of Windows NT.[13] This was done alongside Windows Subsystem for Linux, allowing Unix-like terminal-based software to use the sequences in Windows Console. Unfortunately this defaults to off, but Windows PowerShell 5.1 enabled it. PowerShell 6 made it possible to embed the necessary ESC character into a string with `e.[14] Windows Terminal, introduced in 2019, supports the sequences by default, and Microsoft intends to replace the Windows Console with Windows Terminal.[15]

Color codes work in Visual Studio Code (Terminal).

**ADDITIONAL INFO:**

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/new-experimental-console-features/

Comment: So, there is no solution for OP?

Comment: It seems there is. You can enable it but in requires windows.h. Something i would prefer not to include. But the color codes is not the main problem.

Answer (score 5):

I've been able to enable Color Codes in default Windows terminal using the following code:

```
#ifdef _WIN32

#include <Windows.h>

void enableColors()
{
    DWORD consoleMode;
    HANDLE outputHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if (GetConsoleMode(outputHandle, &consoleMode))
    {
        SetConsoleMode(outputHandle, consoleMode | ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING);
    }
}

#endif
```

Call it once at the start of the `main` function.

Comment: Thanks. I already implemented a slightly longer version that catches possible exceptions and errors and stuff. Although i don´t really understand the code yet, it works. Maybe you could elaborate what your #ifdef _WIN32 does?

Comment: @386 It ensures that this code is compiled only on Windows, because it won't compile on other OS.

Answer (score 0):

Windows terminal supports ANSI escape sequences but not in default. You have to set up in some cases. This is the solution:

Windows Start --> run regedit --> add new variable to HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Console (name: VirtualTerminalLevel type: double word value type: decimal value: 1)